# Is there any easiest way to unzip folders and sub folders using powershell

Tags: powershell

hi i am trying to unzip  folders and sub folders i have tried different ways and script but no luck.
Can some one help on this

```
$Date = Get-Date
#
$folder_date = $Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmmss")


$content = get-childitem 'C:\Deployments'      



$sortedContent = $content |  Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending   

# 1. LIST BACKUPS
write-host "This is the list of all the Deployments  :"

$count = 1
foreach ($item in $sortedContent)
{
#Edit: Now with auto-incrementing counter
Write-Host ("{0}: {1}" -f $count, $item.Name)
$count++ 
}

$itemNumber = Read-Host "Please select which deployments you want to copy "
$itemNumber = $itemNumber -1
if($sortedContent[$itemNumber].PSIsContainer -eq $true)
{ 
    $src = $sortedContent[$itemNumber].FullName + "\"
    $Date = Get-Date
    $folder_date = $Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HHmm")
    $tempPath = 'C:\_Temp\Restore' + $folder_date
    if (!(Test-Path -path $tempPath)) 
    {
        New-Item $tempPath -type directory

    }   

    $TabletzipPath = $src + "table.zip"
    $AdminzipPath = $src + "admin.zip"




    .\unzip.ps1 $src $tempPath
    .\unzip.ps1 $TabletzipPath $tempPath
    .\unzip.ps1 $AdminzipPath $tempPath


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$Shell = new-object -com shell.application
$Zip = $Shell.NameSpace($PathToZip)
ForEach($Item in $Zip.items())
{
    $Shell.Namespace($ExtractPath).copyhere($Item)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your just looking for an easy & quick way of doing this.

You can use this function:

Unzip-File -File C:\location.zip -Destination E:\destination

Need this script:

http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/PowerShell-Function-to-727d6200

Answer (score 0):

Using jar unzipping: copy-paste it into PowerShell ISE or create a .ps1 file with this code:

```
#choose directory where your script is
cd $PSScriptRoot
#do for each file in your directory, -recurse stands for all subfolders, *.jar stands for all files with jar extension
foreach ($file in (dir -Recurse *.jar)) 
{
#Uncomment this to check files this script is going to unzip (don't forget to comment 7z line below to avoid operation)
#Write-Host ("Dir for file " + $file.Name + " is " + $file.Directory)
 
#put here full path to 7z if there is no system env (or just make it) for that
#x stands for eXtract files with full paths
#-o is for output folder (example of usage -oc:\test\)
7z x $file.FullName ("-o"+$file.Directory)
}
```

It should unzip everything you need directly to the folder where your .jar (or any other archive) is.